# Minimal monaco-editor without language support

Tags: vite, monaco-editor

I am trying to configure Monaco as a webcomponent (using vite's lit-ts template) that edits a single, custom language and without lots of Monaco's extra features. (I then want to copy the output to include using a script tag in my main project's index.html)

In my main file I have

```
import {monaco} from "./customMonaco";
// add support for the 1 custom language I do want
import "./mix.contribution.js";
```

In customMonaco.ts I have

```
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/contentWidgets/contentWidgets.js";
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/lineNumbers/lineNumbers.js";
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/lineNumbers/lineNumbers.css";
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/linesDecorations/linesDecorations.js";
import "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/linesDecorations/linesDecorations.css";
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js";
export {monaco};
```

But when I build this I am still getting all the language files.

My vite config is

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: 'src/rmx-monaco.ts',
            formats: ['es']
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: /^lit/,
            // output: {
            //     manualChunks: undefined,
            //     inlineDynamicImports: true,
            //     entryFileNames: "[name].js",
            //     // Prevent vendor.js being created
            //     // prevents adding cache busting
            //     chunkFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
            //     assetFileNames: "rmx-monaco.[ext]",
            // },
        }
    }, server: {port: 5000}
})
```

and next I will uncomment the output section so as to get just 1 js file, but I don't want it to include language support

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/browser-esm-webpack-small) in the `monaco-editor` repo just for this. Look in `index.js`. The current example uses `node_modules` in `..`, and so the imports are a little different from what works with the newest monaco, but if you:

```bash
cd monaco-editor/samples
npm install monaco-editor@0.37.1
cd browser-esm-webpack-small
npm run generate-imports
```

it will update index.js to use imports that work with that monaco version.

I'm using:

```js
import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/coreCommands.js';
import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findController.js';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js';
import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/yaml/yaml.contribution.js';

import editorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker'
```